# Error in Excel 2010, PasteSpecial method of Range Class failed within macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Following is my code that's throwing this error:

> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Error is throwing only when I'm trying to debug.

```
Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells((Rowrange + 7), 2)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues


  ' my complete code

strSheetName = "sheet1"
Sheets(strSheetName).Select
B6 = Range("B6").Value
B7 = Range("B7").Value
Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells((Rowrange + 11), 2)).Select
Selection.Copy

strSheetName = "sheet2"
Sheets(strSheetName).Select
' Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells((Rowrange + 7), 2)).Select
'.Range(Cells(7,1), .Cells(RowRange + 7, 2). PasteSpecial Paste := xlValues
'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
With ActiveSheet
.Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(Rowrange + 7, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End With
```

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: What is the value of `RowRange`?

Comment: Can you show the complete code (including the copy code)

Comment: Where are you copying to do a paste? You need to copy first to do a paste ;)

Comment: Sometimes I randomly get this error (Excel 2003/Windows 7 or XP) and rebooting my computer seems to fix it.  Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (If the above is actually your complete code) you are not copying the data and directly trying to do a paste and hence you are getting that error :)

Is this what you are trying?

```
strSheetName = "Estimated vs Actual Costs"
With Sheets(strSheetName)
    .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(RowRange + 7, 2)).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(RowRange + 7, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End With
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Try this

```
strSheetName = "sheet1"
With Sheets(strSheetName)
    B6 = .Range("B6").Value
    B7 = .Range("B7").Value
    .Range(.Cells(11, 1), .Cells((RowRange + 11), 2)).Copy
End With

strSheetName = "sheet2"
With Sheets(strSheetName)
    .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(RowRange + 7, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End With
```

Comment: :Still have the same error.How to check clipboard data???May be I guess it`s my data problem.xlValues data tat`s coming is '-4165'.

Comment: an you upload your excel file?

Comment: :yea sid I do upload excel file.

Comment: upload the file in wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: :I work for a company,I`m not allowed to do that,as it`s illegal.No other way??

Comment: Also the above is not the complete code. Your code shoul start with `Sub Something()` and will end at `End Sub` Can you paste that complete code?

Comment: :yeah I know how to debug.The complete function is too big to paste here,more over it`s complicate to understand.That`s why i have put only the required code.

Comment: I have tested the above code with different scenarios and it works perfectly. I can't see your workbook... I can't see your code... I don't know what else to suggest :) If you delete the rest of the sheets and then upload the file. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid that kind of error is to only use fully qualified ranges:

```
With Sheets("The name of the sheet")
    .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(RowRange + 7, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End With
```

Or: `With ActiveSheet` if you know the sheet is already selected.

Also note that selecting is not necessary.

Comment: I`m using Excel 2010,but the report which I`m working on was created in Excel 2003.

Comment: @SiddharthRout:I have put the code.Please check.And RowRange is '2'.

Comment: @user1382191 Where is the part of the code where you `Copy`? Are you sure something is in the clipboard when you are at the line you show in your question?